# How do I let this 2D array assignment not store 'nil' in an element when the condition is not met?

Tags: ruby

So I am cycling through a list of links on a page with Nokogiri and pushing all the links onto a 2D array. The issue is that it is pushing `nil` in some elements which I don't want.

How do I force it to skip the elements that are nil, so my array just has links and not some links and some nil values?

See code:

```
url = 'http://www.craigslist.org/about/sites'

def my_list(url)
    root = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    list = root.css("a").map do |link|
        if link[:href] =~ /http/
            [link.text, link[:href]]   
        end        
    end
end
```

Thoughts?

P.S. I tried `if link[:href].nil?`, but I am not sure how to tell it to skip that particular `link` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post-process the list, as root doesn't seem to support all the collection methods, try this at the end of your method to clean it up. It'll drop all the nils.

```
list = list.reject {|x| x.nil?}
```

Comment: It will go through your list twice. one with #map and one with #reject. it's good with a small list though.

Comment: Or even more tersely: `list.reject!(&:nil?)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
list = root.css("a").reject!{|l| l[:href].nil?}.map do | link |
```

Comment: This seems a bit too verbose and awkward....Paul suggested a more elegant way. Thanks for the effort though!

Comment: It's the same method used in one line